# PHP - Plesk - Cron - Allowed memory size exhausted?

Tags: cron, php, plesk, memory-limit

```
ini_set('max_execution_time',0);
ini_set('memory_limit','1000M');
```

These are the first two lines at the very top of my script.

I was under the impression if I ran something via cron memory limits didn't apply, but I was wrong. Safe mode is off and when I test to see if these values are being set they are but I keep getting the good ol' "PHP Fatal: Memory exhausted" error.

Any ideas what I may be doing wrong? And whats the "more elegant way" of writing "infinite" for the "memory limit" value is it -1 or something?

Answer (score 0):

possible that suhosin is running on your Server? If yes, you have to set the "suhosin.memory_limit" inside your php.ini.

Suhosin does now allow to allocate more memory, even if safemode is off.

Comment: if it didn't come with the php installation, it's not on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Changed memory limit to -1 instead of '1000M' now everything works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use non-numeric values ("M", "K") outside php.ini proper. Setting `10000000` would probably work.